# Empty line after dirtree?

Tags: spacing, formatting, alignment, dirtree

I have a dirtree in my latex file, followed by a block of text.
However, between the end of the diretree and the start of the textblock there is no space.
I want to add an empty line in between, but I couldn't get it to work.
I tried  `\newline` and also `\\` but I am told: `There's no line here to end.`

Example:

```
\dirtree{%
.1 folder1.
.2 files.
.3 test.jpg.
.3 bla.mp4.
.2 stuff.txt.
.2 morestuff.txt.
}
This is some text.
```

Adding `\newline` after the `}` has no effect. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, edit your question to include the fragment into a compilable document that people can use to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of items of the "to do" list of the `dirtree` documentation is to create above and below skip values to solve this problem, but this hasn't ever been done, and since the package was last revised in 2012 it's unlikely to happen. You can patch the commands using `etoolbox` to give a uniform spacing around every tree:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\dirtree}{\bigskip}{}{}
\pretocmd{\dirtree}{\bigskip}{}{}
\begin{document}
This is some text.

\dirtree{%
.1 /.
.2 bin.
.2 home.
.3 jeancome.
.4 texmf.
.5 tex.
.6 latex.
.7 dirtree.
.3 jeancomeson.
}

This is some text.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I wasn't aware that the package is outdated since 2012. However, your workaround seems to work just fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Kyu96 Being old doesn't mean being outdated. The package still works well, and there's no reason to think that it won't in the future. My point was just that future updates with new features seem unlikely.